# Activator.CreateInstance() overloads have different return types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm using `Activator.CreateInstance` to build object in my project. 
I've noted that depending on what overload of `CreateInstance` you call, you get either the object you requested or an [ObjectHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Why is this? it seems very counterintuitive to me.

```
public static Object CreateInstance( Type type )

public static ObjectHandle CreateInstance( string assemblyName, string typeName )
```

taked from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm wondering if it is something to do with the fact that if you have a type it will tell you more about the object and its .NET compatibility or something than the two strings which might be giving you legacy objects or something. Its the only real difference I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of

```
public static Object CreateInstance( Type type )
```

it could be possible that you are instantiating an object which is not MarshalByRefObject which means instead of a proxy it is a real object.

But in case of

```
public static ObjectHandle CreateInstance( string assemblyName, string typeName )
```

it could be possible, that the object being created is either getting instantiated within the active .net execution context or it could be possible that the assembly's type is configured to hook up to a remote object via an underlying proxy returned by `Unwrap()` method of `ObjectHandle`, the remote object could be created in another `AppDomain`. Another `AppDomain` could exist within the same process, a different process on same machine or a remote process on a different machine using `.NET Remoting`.

Another difference is, the proxy object returned by `ObjectHandle.Unwrap()` may have a lease time. If expired then any method call on this proxy object will fail! whereas the `CreateInstance(Type)` method's returned object is real object instead of proxy.

So, both methods are different.

Comment: so, the advantage of having an ObjectHandle its that the assembly for that class doesn't have to be in the active context?

Comment: ObjectHandle can gives you a proxy to the real object if that object is created in a different appdomain. You can use RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(testObj) to check if the object a proxy... A false object means it is a real object created just like using new.